# XGBoost on Python

Tags: classification, python

Hi could someone explain what the num_round parameter is for ?

it is not well explained in the official doc
http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html

on that page, a (typical ?) value of 10 is used
it is also said, that as ETA goes down, this parameter should go up but that about it.

Comment: Do you mean `num_boost_round`?

Answer (score 1):

It's the number of boosting rounds you want, which is equivalent to the number of trees your model will use. Because tree models really overfit data, the eta parameter is used to shrink the weights of a prior boost round (I think it just multiplies each weight by $\eta\in[0,1]$) . This is why if you increase the number of rounds, you want to decrease eta (i.e. apply more shrinkage to weights = less overfitting after each boost) as you increase the number of rounds.